# Is theory of mind formation accelerated by bilingualism?

Tags: language, theory-of-mind

[Kovács (2009)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19120412) reported that bilingual children were better at solving a [false belief task](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_mind#False-belief_task) critical to the fully developed theory of mind (ToM).

Has this study been replicated or criticized by others? I.e. is it uncontroversial that bilingualism accelerates ToM development?